# Recreate iOS 10 search bar like in the Maps application

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisearchbar, ios10

I'm new to iOS development and I'm trying to recreate the look and feel of the search bar in the Maps application on iOS 10.

I have manage to create the search bar and make it work. The problem is that I can't change the title for the little bar above the textfield like in Maps. I known how to change it for some other text but not how to change it for an image/icon.

In addition to that, I have no ideas of how I'm supposed to change the alignment of the placeholder to the left.

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Here is some image of the current application and of what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance for the answers!

[image: Actual application]
[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this right, your 'title' on top of the input text field is an image ? If that's it, you should definitively change it to a label, and your problem is solved.

EDIT:

You should get ride of the prompt, and add your UISearchBar into a view. Then you can add an image for the bar into that view. To me this is the easiest solution.

Comment: That's not it. The text "Title" in the first image is set with the prompt property of the UiSearchBar. I want to replace it by the line/bar of the present in the second image. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: The bar in the second picture is there to pull up the view, are you aware of that ?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly why I want it.

Comment: Thanks ! That's what I did !